# How to convert android image view to pdf using i text library in Android studio

Tags: android, pdf, textview, imageview, itext

hi developers i need some solution for you guys..

i'm trying to write code to convert text views and image view into pdf format for that i'm using iText library

this is my code

```
   Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

    //textview to pdf

    Paragraph basicInfo = new Paragraph();
    basicInfo.add("\n \n \n Basic Information \n \n \n");
    basicInfo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    document.add(basicInfo);


      //image view to pdf

    Paragraph personalInfo = new Paragraph();
    Image image = Image.getInstance ("usericon.png");
    personalInfo.add(image);

    personalInfo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    document.add(personalInfo);
```

its successfully created pdf document.but in pdf document its storing only "Basic Information" text

not showing an image

according to code usericon.png this image is available in drawable folder

text views point of view no problem is giving

but image view point of giving problem..

its giving some runtime exception like this

> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /2130837808: open failed:
>   ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
> 06-20 15:07:51.874 32319-32319/com.appchant.mm_sangamadmin_android
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:244) 06-20 15:07:51.874
>   32319-32319/com.appchant.mm_sangamadmin_android W/System.err:     at
>   com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:340)
>
> W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed:
>   ENOENT (No such file or directory)

can anybody solve this issue i need exactly

i want to write a pdf for textviews and image view using iText library in android studio

text view point of view no problem is coming but image view point of view problems are coming.

thanks in advance

Comment: Error stating clearly that file not found. so before going to create a PDF file, check that directory and file is exist or not..

Comment: Check this tutorial for creating a pdf file with image. http://www.concretepage.com/itext/add-image-in-pdf-using-itext-in-java

Comment: i have already image in drawable folder eventhough its showing not there like that i mean above exception

Comment: i tried this link http://www.concretepage.com/itext/add-image-in-pdf-using-itext-in-java-->same exception coming

Comment: find the solution for your exception and solve it.

Comment: actually i tried lot of ways even though i failed can you tell me why its coming if image available also

Comment: Add the code of all of your lot of ways to your question, and for each of them, add your fail.